# How to use the Retrofit for Parse JSON values in android?

Tags: android, json, magento

Hi i have trying to get the data from Magento using Rest API with the method of Retrofit but i referred many sites but i cant get any hope please help me to write correct coding i ll be helpfull..

My JSON format:

```
[{"id":2153,"sku":"62928","name":"3 ROSES DUST 250G TEA REFILL","attribute_set_id":4,"price":128,"status":1,"visibility":4,"type_id":"simple","created_at":"2017-08-15 13:21:32","updated_at":"2017-09-14 06:53:31","extension_attributes":{"stock_item":{"item_id":4150,"product_id":2153,"stock_id":1,"qty":45,"is_in_stock":true,"is_qty_decimal":false,"show_default_notification_message":false,"use_config_min_qty":true,"min_qty":0,"use_config_min_sale_qty":1,"min_sale_qty":1,"use_config_max_sale_qty":true,"max_sale_qty":10000,"use_config_backorders":true,"backorders":0,"use_config_notify_stock_qty":true,"notify_stock_qty":1,"use_config_qty_increments":true,"qty_increments":0,"use_config_enable_qty_inc":true,"enable_qty_increments":false,"use_config_manage_stock":true,"manage_stock":true,"low_stock_date":null,"is_decimal_divided":false,"stock_status_changed_auto":0}},"product_links":[],"options":[],"media_gallery_entries":[{"id":171,"media_type":"image","label":"","position":1,"disabled":false,"types":["image","small_image","thumbnail","swatch_image"],"file":"\/6\/2\/62928.png"}],"tier_prices":[],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"description","value":"
3 ROSES DUST 250G TEA REFILL<\/p>"},{"attribute_code":"short_description","value":"

3 ROSES DUST 250G TEA REFILL<\/p>"},{"attribute_code":"special_price","value":"121.6000"},{"attribute_code":"special_from_date","value":"2017-08-17 00:00:00"},{"attribute_code":"special_to_date","value":"2018-08-31 00:00:00"},{"attribute_code":"cost","value":"128.0000"},{"attribute_code":"meta_title","value":"3 ROSES DUST 250G TEA REFILL"},{"attribute_code":"meta_description","value":"3 ROSES DUST 250G TEA REFILL"},{"attribute_code":"image","value":"\/6\/2\/62928.png"},{"attribute_code":"small_image","value":"\/6\/2\/62928.png"},{"attribute_code":"thumbnail","value":"\/6\/2\/62928.png"},{"attribute_code":"news_from_date","value":"2017-08-17 11:51:23"},{"attribute_code":"custom_design_from","value":"2017-08-17 11:51:23"},{"attribute_code":"category_ids","value":["2","58","132"]},{"attribute_code":"options_container","value":"container2"},{"attribute_code":"required_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"has_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"msrp_display_actual_price_type","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"url_key","value":"3-roses-dust-250g-tea-refill"},{"attribute_code":"gift_message_available","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"tax_class_id","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"swatch_image","value":"\/6\/2\/62928.png"}]}]
```

My needed Attributes are :
name, sku, price, extension_attributes:"media_gallery":"file", attribute_code:"special_price",value:"121.6000"

I have set some coding as per my knowledge as follows:

Product:

public class Product {

```
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;

    @SerializedName("extension_attributes")
    @Expose
    private ExtensionAttributes extensionAttributes;

    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ExtensionAttributes getExtensionAttributes() {
        return extensionAttributes;
    }

    public void setExtensionAttributes(ExtensionAttributes extensionAttributes) {
        this.extensionAttributes = extensionAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "sku='" + sku + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", extensionAttributes=" + extensionAttributes +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Extension attribute:

```
public class ExtensionAttributes {

    @SerializedName("media_gallery_entries")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Media_Gallery> media;

    public ArrayList<Media_Gallery> getMedia() {
        return media;
    }

    public void setMedia(ArrayList<Media_Gallery> media) {
        this.media = media;
    }
}
```

Media_Gallery:

public class Media_Gallery {

```
    @SerializedName("file")
    @Expose
    private String file;

    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Please check this above coding is correct..
But i have doubt in mainactivity that is how i should set this all above values in my recycler view please help me current mainactivity coding is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Product> listing;
    List<Media_Gallery> listing1;

    private  final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycle_retrofit);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        listing = new ArrayList<>();
        listing1 = new ArrayList<Media_Gallery>();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://alagendransupermart.com/mageapi/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APiService service = retrofit.create(APiService.class);
        Call<List<Product>> call=   service.getbookdetails();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {

                List<Product> list = response.body();
                Product product = null;
                String image=null;
                for (int i =0 ;i<list.size();i++){
                    product = new Product();
                    String name = list.get(i).getName();
                    String color = list.get(i).getSku();
                    String price = list.get(i).getPrice();

                    ArrayList<Media_Gallery> media = response.body().get(i).getExtensionAttributes().getMedia();

                    for(int j = 0; j<media.size(); j++){
                         image = media.get(j).getFile();

                    }

                    Media_Gallery med = new Media_Gallery();
                    med.setFile(image);

                    product.setPrice(price);
                    product.setSku(color);
                    product.setName(name);
                    listing.add(product);
                    listing1.add(med);
                }


                Recycleradapter recyclerAdapter = new Recycleradapter(MainActivity.this,listing);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,2);
                // RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingdecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG,"Something went wrong :"+t.getMessage());


            }
        });

    }
}
```